# Find the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ centred at $3i$ over the domain $|z-3i|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

We can rewrite the region $|z-3i|<3$ as $\left| \frac{z-3i}{3}\right|<1$. Then using the fact that $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$, we can obtain the following power series
$$\frac{1}{1-(z-3i)/3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{z-3i}{3}\right)^n \implies \frac{1}{3(1-i)-z}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{z-3i}{3}\right)^n$$
I am unsure how to use the power series to expand $(1-z)^{-1}$.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The power series expansion of $(z-1)^{-1}$ around $z=3i$ ought to have domain $|z-3i|<|1-3i|=\sqrt{10}$. In general, the radius of convergence around a point will be the distance to the nearest pole. As for the series expansion, write $$\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{(z-3i)+(3i-1)}=\frac{1}{(3i-1)\Big(1+\frac{z-3i}{3i-1}\Big)}. $$

Comment: I do not understand anything . Why does the "domain $|z-2i|<3$" become the "region $|z-3i|<3$"?this kind of simple example is useful to clarify the notion of analytic function, not to confuse it.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Sorry that was a typo. I fixed it now

Comment: @runway44 What if this was centred on the real number axis? let's say at $-3$.

Comment: Same logic. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall u\in \mathbb C$ such that $|u|<1$,$\frac{1}{1-u} = \sum_{n=\color{red}0}^\infty u^n\color{green}{(*)}$

Let $z\in \mathbb C$. Let's pose $z=3i+h$, with $h=z-3i$.
Then, $\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-(3i+h)}=\frac{1}{1-3i-h}=\frac{1}{(1-3i)\times(1-\frac{h}{1-3i})}$

Then, according to $\color{green}{(*)}$, $$\forall h\in \mathbb C,  |\frac{h}{1-3i}|<1(i.e. |h|<\sqrt{10)},$$
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{h}{1-3i}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^n}{(1-3i)^n}$$
And finally, $\forall z\in \mathbb C |z-3i|<\sqrt{10 },$ $$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-3i)^{n+1}}(z-3i)^n$$

(I hope this will help.)